# Where can I find kde qml object api?

Tags: widget, qml, kde-plasma, plasmoid

Excuse me for my bad English.
I am write a kde plasmoid for show info of top maximized window on the top panel. I need to know what window is maximized and is over other windows. I by use of org.kde.tasmanager know that a specific window is maximized or not. but I dont know what window is over and what window is below. which package I must use for this. and I dont know where is api for kde qml objects to find this.
Thanks.

Comment: I found a reference to `org.kde.kwindowsystem` [here](https://cgit.kde.org/plasma-desktop.git/tree/applets/window-list/contents/ui/main.qml) and [this](https://api.kde.org/frameworks/kdeclarative/html/classKWindowSystemProxy.html) seems to be the exposed API. Nothing for your use case though I think

Comment: Thanks Kevin for your attention. but I didn't find solution of my problem in above links.

Comment: It seem that KWindowSystem::stackingOrder() is what i want now how use it in a qml file. thanks

Comment: if the second link is, as I suspect, the QML wrapper API, then `stackingOrder()` is not yet part of the exported functions.
You could write a plasmoid that has QML and C++ and expose the functionality yourself